# Trying to make a countdown with a twist

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, while-loop, countdown

I'm trying to make a countdown timer like little script. I want it to look like this:

```
0 years left until your event.
0 months left until your event.
10 days left until your event.
234 hours left until your event.
14020 minutes left until your event.
841166 seconds left until your event.
```

As you can see it's not a "normal" countdown. I want it to be like this, total amount of seconds, total amount of minutes left etc. Now I'm running into trouble trying to make it actually count-down. Just the seconds are working fine, I'm using this piece of code for that:

```
def secondsLeft(eventDate):
    while secondsUntil:
        toPrint = "%s seconds left until your event." %(secondsUntil)
        print(toPrint, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        secondsUntil -= 1
```

However, when trying to do the same for the minutes, replacing with time.sleep(60) it's not printing out the seconds anymore!

I think it has to do with the while loop. However, I don't know what to do about it... Any help in the right direction is appreciated!!

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Calculate the number of minutes, hours etc. **from** the number of seconds.

Comment: Alternatively, read a little about datetime objects, make your computations with a single datetime object and then just print it using the different granularities you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping at a constant rate with high precision for signal sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774186/looping-at-a-constant-rate-with-high-precision-for-signal-sampling)

Comment: @Błotosmętek so you're saying throw everything into one line and calculation, into the def secondsLeft? At the moment I've put all the numbers seperate.

Comment: @JosepValls thanks for reminding me about that. I was using datetime in my script, however I thought this problem had to do more with the while loop and stuff in stead of the calculation part. I'll make sure to look into datetime

Comment: Thanks guys, you've pointed me in the right direction. Now I have something that works, however I need to clear out the entire command line every second to make it look pretty. Any way to use carriage return on a block of text in stead of one line of text?

Answer (score 0):

If you wait a minute the whole program will be stopped for a minute. It can't decrease the seconds. What you want to do is, keep waiting only a second per while interation and add this line `mins, secs = divmod(secondsUntil, 60)`. You can print mins for the minutesUntil

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see how that works. However, I'm running into trouble printing the lines in the way I want to print them. The carriage return is giving me trouble, is there any alternative to this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the CR is giving you trouble?