# How to write an autoscript in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got temperature, pressure, and altitude readings on my `PI` using a sensor:

1. The problem is, to see the results, I have to execute the `code.py` every time by myself. I am trying to automate it somehow so it will keep running itself for the time I want.
2. Once that is automated, would like to save the results and analyze the output after some time.

Is there a way I can write code for both the tasks?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. If you're running Raspbian, you can use the `crontab` to run any program at intervals. Or `time.sleep()` in Python to pause.

Comment: 2. You can save the results to a file (typically `csv`, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)). Then you read the file later on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping at a constant rate with high precision for signal sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774186/looping-at-a-constant-rate-with-high-precision-for-signal-sampling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things required here. First a script i.e `code.py` to log the functional behavior like `temperature, pressure, and altitude` readings along with error/response during the process. Another is the script executions logs i.e a success or failure during the scheduled time and other system logs.

For first job, you have to do by your self but ensure to have a `logger` module in place to log the process flow.

For Second job, you can use OS provided scheduler `crontab` for `Linux` based os. For example to execute script every minutes

```
* * * * * python /home/script/code.py > /home/script/code.log 2>&1
```

For more about scheduler jobs, you can refer [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

Answer (score 0):

The time module is your friend here. You can set up an infinite loop with `while True:` and use `time.sleep(secs)` at the end of the loop (after output).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use additional controller script like this:

```
import subprocess;
import time;
import sys;

x = True;
while x:
    while exit_code!=0:
        try:
            exit_code = subprocess.check_call(['python', 'collect_data.py', '-cli_args_if_needed']);
        except:
            print(sys.exec_info()[1]);
            print('Relaunching in 5 seconds');
            time.sleep(5)
```