# How to compare next datetime in a list with the current one

Tags: python, datetime

```
import os  
from datetime import datetime  

InFileName = r'path\Snapshot_list.txt'
#OutFileName = r'path\Process.bat'

InFile = open(InFileName)
for line in InFile:

s='20'
line = s[:2] + line[2:] [:6]
datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(line,'%Y%m%d')
newformat = datetimeobject.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print (newformat)

InFile.close()
```

The format I get is :

2012-05-30
2012-05-31
2012-06-01
2012-06-02
2012-06-03
2012-06-05

I want to compare every line with the line before ,   if line 2 != line 1 + 1   then I will write 'things' in outfile

Comment: Save the previous value for the next iteration?

Comment: Yes it consists in saving the previous value for the next iteration, but do I need to set a condiftion IF in the same loop or save the list in a temporary file where I do a new iteration? I am a beginner could you please help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813624/compare-lists-in-python-while-looping/14813874#14813874 for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import timedelta    

prev_date= None
for line in InFile:
    datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(line,'%Y%m%d')
    if datetimeobject-timedelta(days=1) != prev_date:
        outfile.write('things')
    prev_date= datetimeobject
```

Comment: for clarity, you could use `expected_date = datetime_object + DAY`. Note: it doesn't matter in this case but in general [*do not subtract naive datetime objects that represent local time*; it fails in many cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279). Also, [24 hours ago and yesterday could be different time moments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15344710/4279) (again, it does not matter in this particular case because the input does not specify the time). See also, [How can I subtract a day from a python date?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/441147/4279)